# How to trigger method when clicking a Buefy tabs?

Tags: javascript, bulma, buefy

The question says it all but I have 3 tabs in Buefy, the first two (summary and details) I have got covered and work correctly as expected but the third tab is a logout button so when I click it I want to fire a method to alert("").

My buefy tabs are just from the standard page [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/tabs) and look like:

```html
    <b-tabs type="is-toggle" expanded>
        <b-tab-item label="Pictures" icon="google-photos"></b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Music" icon="library-music"></b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Logout" icon="logout"></b-tab-item>
</b-tabs>
```

I have tried putting an on-click into the b-tab-item but that didn't work and the docs say there is an event:

```
input   Triggers when tab is clicked    index: Number
```

But I don't know how to capture that the third tab has been clicked to fire some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with all Vue event handlers, the @input event handler will automatically pass the event data to your methods. In this case, as the [docs](https://buefy.org/documentation/tabs/) state, that event data is simply the index of the button tab clicked.

```
<template>
    <b-tabs v-model="activeTab" type="is-boxed" @input="tabClicked(activeTab)"
        <b-tab-item label="Pictures" icon="google-photos"></b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Music" icon="library-music"></b-tab-item>
        <b-tab-item label="Videos" icon="video"></b-tab-item>
    </b-tabs>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activeTab: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    tabClicked(index) {
      if (index === 2) alert('Index 2 is the third button');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like programmatically jumping to a tab is impossible. Setting `activeTab` to index or name of tab doesn't seem to automatically switch to that tab which is strange